# Angular single filter/input for single and chained comparison

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm building a sample project that displays a table to a user based on their column show/hide preferences and a combination of regex filtering on certain fields and greater than/less than values for others.

I've implemented a basic greater than filter in Angular by using:

```
app.filter('greaterThan', function() {
  return function(input, field, gt){
    var out = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
      if (input[i][field] > gt) {
        out.push(input[i]);
      }
    }
    return out;
  };
});
```

and implementing a less than is just as easy.

However this would use two input fields/scope variables to filter the table I'm displaying. And with 8 columns that would require this type of filter the code would get more bloated than I'd care for.

Is there an Angular solution that allows a user to write out: '0 < x < 10' or something similar in a filter field that would then be usable on my table or am I going to have to go into a bunch of string parsing for all the different cases?

Comment: No, Angular, JavaScript and no other language I know understands `0 < x < 10`. But what about creating a `range:from:to` filter?